# Need some advice regarding multi model forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a view where users will be able to fill in 3 forms (I'll probably use javascript to let users change between the 3 tabs):

1. Model info
2. Portfolio info
3. Contact info

All of these models have `belongs_to :user` in their model as all of the information provided in these forms should belong to the user that created them.

What would be the best way according to Rails to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)

some useful screencasts:

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
>
> http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Users should be able to edit the forms seperately... nested forms edits everything at once, I don't want that :/

Comment: so just make 3 forms, that's it

Comment: I put the 3 models together but I am getting an error when I click the submit button of the model because of the validation.. if i enter proper values it works just fine.

I'm thinking it would be better if i just displayed the form itself via ajax instead of doing a 3 in one form.